# How to get output to a terminal's stdout after filling the terminal with other information?

Tags: centos, terminal, output

The problem is simple: I ran a python parsing script overnight last night, and it failed spitting out an exception error message. More importantly, the script printed to stdout which file it was parsing when said error occurred.

Later this morning, I inadvertently did an 'll' in the same terminal. Since the folder has the 10s of thousands of files my script was parsing through, the 'll' output filled my terminal completely, and I can't get to the error message any more.  This was the only command I have run in this terminal since the error message.

I think I fixed my script, but I need to know what file the script failed on so that I can re-test it effectively. Is there any way I can recover things printed to stdout in this terminal?

Comment: your only chance is using the scrollback buffer with shift+pgup. if it is to small, then that output is lost.

Comment: @IporSircer Yes, that buffer is too small, and only has output from the ll.